# Parse output of a command in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am running a heroku command `heroku pg:backups:capture --app appname` to backup a database, which returns an output in the terminal like this:

```
Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue running.
Use heroku pg:backups:info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Starting backup of postgresql-xxxxxxxxxx... done
Backing up DATABASE to b007... done
```

How can I store the backup name `b007` to a variable automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe your command to `sed` to extract the desired string:

```
 dbname=$(heroku pg:backups:capture --app appname | sed -n 's/.*DATABASE to \([^\.]*\)\.\.\..*/\1/p')
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. After running the heroku command, the terminal interface shows the progress, which looks something like this https://ibb.co/ZVQvW0W, and after the backup is complete, it shows as `done`. Maybe that's why the command you suggested doesn't work?

Comment: @vikiboy try adding `2>&1` before the pipe. It could be that heroku uses stderr instead of stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect via pipe `|` the output of the program to

`grep "Backing up DATABASE to " | awk '{print substr($5,0,5)}'`

It would be:

`var=$(heroku pg:backups:capture --app appname | grep "Backing up DATABASE to " | awk '{print substr($5,0,5)}')`

Comment: I edited the output line in the question. Will that update your answer? Sorry for the trouble. I am seeing `time` and `check` as the output with your suggestion.

Comment: Depending on the output you just have to change the parameter you give to `grep` and `awk`. `grep` will filter all the lines that do not contain the string you provide, and awk will take out the part you want from the line.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic possibility:

```
while read -r line
do echo "$line"
   case "$line" in
   Backing\ up\ DATABASE\ to\ *done)
       backup="${line%%... done}"
       backup="${backup##* }"
   esac
done < <( heroku pg:backups:capture --app appname )
echo "Backup: [$backup]"
```

Comment: `Backup: []` Tried it. I am getting this.

Comment: Make sure the match string is accurate. This worked for what I copy/pasted from your OP, but if the output differs you'll have to tweak.